# Regex - simple phone number validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, phone-number

I need to check / replace a Phone number in a Form Field with regex and it should really be simple. 
I can't find Solutions in this Format:

"place number"
so: "0521 123456789"

Nothing else should work. No special Characters, no country etc.
Just "0521 123456789"

Would be great if someone could provide a solution as I'm not an Expert with regex (and PHP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following RegEx:

```
^0[1-9]\d{2}\s\d{9}$
```

That will match it how it is exactly

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d21i)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
^        # String Starts with ...
0        # First Digit is 0
[1-9]    # Second Digit is from 1 to 9 (i.e. NOT 0)
\d{2}    # 2 More Digits
\s       # Whitespace (use a [Space] character instead to only allow spaces, and not [Tab]s)
\d{9}    # Digit 9 times exactly (123456789)
$        # ... String Ends with
```

Comment: Okay, i tried with "\d{3,5}\s\d{4,14}" cause the prefix (i.e. 0521) sometimes are longer etc. BUT theres still a little mistake, the special char + is accepted, the regex should check if there was used ONLY Numbers

Comment: @DanielMcDonald you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the pattern: `^\d{4}\s\d{9}$` or use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) if the number could occur anywhere in a text: `\b\d{4}\s\d{9}\b`

Comment: uhhh okay, nearly perfekt. Now it requires that the first Number should always be ZERO "0" and the second Number can be anything but not 0 (Zero) ... so "0521 1234567" or "040 23456" .....

Comment: @DanielMcDonald I updated my answer, does it work now?

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for reminding me to use `^` and `$`, I updated my answer

Comment: THANK YOU! We will take this Solution as following: ^0[1-9]\d{1,3}\s\d{3,14}$ this is exactly what we needed.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP` code:

```
$regex = '~\d{4}\h\d{9}~';
$str = '0521 123456789';
preg_match($regex, $str, $match);
```

See a <kbd>[demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/kwDOQB)</kbd>.
To allow **only** this pattern (i.e. no others characters), you can *anchor* it to the beginning and end:

```
$regex = '~^\d{4}\h\d{9}$~';
```

Comment: i didn't downvote your answer :O.... Thanks for help. I gave the second answer some comments.

Comment: @DanielMcDonald If either Jan or my answered answered your question, please consider marking one as accepted. Thanks!